# What is the simplest way to send data from JApplet to JavaScript?

Tags: java, php, javascript, applet

I'm having a HTML page with an applet that gathers data and then is supposed to send this data through JavaScript call, JS sends it to PHP file.

I can send the arguments and values by GET method, but is there something better? 
Can I use JSON for example in this applet? How do I send it to JavaScript?

The applet should not be signed, so I can't add anything fancy there or can I?

Thanks for any tips/pointers.

**Edit:**
I should have probably put it in some other words: "What's the most universal way of sending data (>2kb) from JApplet to JavaScript?" I'd like it to run on as many browsers as possible (I'm aware that some people don't even have java installed).

Answer (score 4):

> What is the simplest way to send data from Java JApplet to Javascript?

Probably this:

```
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument
    (new URL("javascript:someJavaScriptFunction(" + params + ");"));
```

---

This technique I saw recently on Real's How To under [Call Javascript from a Java applet](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html).  That site is always my first place to check for tasks to do with Java/JS interaction.  Besides that technique, other ways of passing data Java<->JavaScript are detailed and (for the most part) demonstrated.

I just posted one 'simple' way.

Comment: This solution reeks of "eval" and moreover, it touches the URL -- what if you have a page where you don't want to touch the URL (because you're using the hash to store state etc.).

Comment: @Ates: "it touches the URL" What does that mean?  Visit [this sand-boxed applet](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version&format=TSV) and tell me if the URL changes.  It uses the technique shown above in order to (hopefully) copy the data from the applet to the HTML based text area.  The URL in the address bar does not change in this late model FF using 1.6.0_24 Oracle Java (if that is what you meant).

Comment: @RealHowTo:  I got it from [code on your site](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html). +2 to your site. ;)

Comment: This is in fact simple, and it works. I have a problem sending more data, so I'd like to send for example and array or an JSON object and recieve it on JS side. Do you know some common library that is on every JRE that can do that?

Comment: @cradox23: There's no built-in library for encoding JSON, but there are [plenty out there](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+json).  The cool part is that JSON is valid Javascript, so you can just pop it right in without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke javascript functions, and in general communicate with javascript through `netscape.javascript.JSObject`. [See here](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html). An example:

```
JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
win.call("receiveDataFromApplet", new Object[] {param1, param2, param3});
```

This will call the desired function with the given arguments.

`JSObject` is part of `JRE/plugin.jar`, so it will run on every JRE. But you will have to add it to your classpath (in your IDE) in order to compile the applet.

Comment: Will this work with all browsers? `To compile Java code to take advantage of JSObject, you must have the package netscape.javascript in the CLASSPATH.` So will it run in applets withouth hassling users?

Comment: @cradox23 JSObject is part of `plugin.jar` of every JRE.  You will just need to add that jar to the classpath when compiling the applet.

Comment: @cradox23 "Will this work with all browsers?"  Not all browsers have Java installed.  Of the browsers that do, the vast majority are 1.3+, but any that run 1.2 or 1.1 would not include the `JSObject`.  AFAIR the name of the Jar containing the `JSObject` class also changed a while ago.  Ah yes, there it is in the How To page.  Pre 1.4.2 it was called `jaws.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

As of JRE 1.6.27 and higher IE 6+ (don't know if it is IE only) will get focus everytime a function is executed through the getAppletContext method. If you do not want this you're better of using JSObject.